# Comment traduire « steep learning curve » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Pour parler de la difficulté d'acquisition d'une nouvelle connaissance/compétence, on utilise parfois en anglais l'expression *[steep learning curve](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/what-is-meant-by-steep-learning-curve)*.

Comment traduire cette expression le plus fidèlement possible tout en sachant que [son sens est double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve#Common_terms) car elle peut signifier que l'apprentissage est simple ou au contraire compliqué.

Existe-t-il une expression concise que l'on pourrait employer ici ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**learning curve** donnera probablement (et très littéralement) **courbe d'apprentissage**.

En revanche, la traduction de *steep* donne lieu à pas mal de variantes possibles en fonction du sens précis à donner à l'expression. Pour se donner une idée de la diversité des choix (examples en vrac : *longue*, *ardue*, *abrupte*, *raide*, mais aussi *accélérée* (!)), on pourra utilement jeter un oeil à [linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=steep%20learning%20curve) qui se révèle ici très précieux.

Comment: Je me demandais si une expression unique pouvait traduire les deux sens possibles mais _a priori_ je resterai donc avec **courbe d'apprentissage ardue** d'un côté, et **apprentissage accéléré** de l'autre. Merci !

Comment: @Yannick: je ne sais pas ce que tu traduis, mais « courbe ardue » n'a aucun sens. To comme en anglais la seule chose qui ait du sens c'est « to be on a steep learning curve » (apprendre en urgence, apprentissage accéléré) comme l'indique la réponse de BlueTrin.

Comment: Autant pour moi en effet, je voulais parler d'**apprentissage ardu**...

Answer (score 4):

We were on a steep learning curve: *Nous avons dû apprendre très vite* (or *apprendre rapidement*).

In common (technically incorrect) usage, “steep learning curve” is meant to indicate that to learn the subject/technique takes a long time and is difficult. 
This second meaning would be translated better by “*apprentissage ardu*”.

Answer (score 3):

On peut le traduire par **barrière d'entrée élevée**.

Answer (score -2):

L'expression « steep learning curve » est un exemple de « [management speak](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Management_speak) » ou « [business speak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_speak) », un style d'anglais arrogant, caractérisé d'ignorance, et [très](http://www.independent.co.uk/student/career-planning/getting-job/being-modern-management-speak-2313025.html) [détesté](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/7457287.stm).  Je crains qu'elle ne résulte en un style de français encore pire, si on n'essaie bien d'améliorer son choix de mots en anglais avant d'aborder une traduction.

Comment: L'expression en question n'apparaît dans aucun des liens que tu donnes. Ta remarque (dont je ne suis pas sûr de deviner le sens de la dernière phrase) ne semble rien apporter. Même si elles sont employées à outrance ces expressions ont tout de même un sens. S'il s'agissait de traduire une faute d'usage — pourquoi pas —, ou de conserver une éventuelle lourdeur, je pense que l'auteur de la question l'aurait mentionné.

Comment: C'est aussi une expression courante dans le monde de l'informatique, [par exemple à propos d'éditeurs de texte](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/988/19765), en général [à propos d'interfaces utilisateur](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/9369/12843).

Comment: @Evpok, jete un œil aux premiers résultats d'une recherche, à mon avis c'est juste une expression courante, pas plus dans le monde de l'informatique qu'ailleurs :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez je ne parlais que de *mon* expérience. :)

Comment: Quoique très courante, l'expression est toutefois du même _style_ précis que celles dans les liens que j'ai donnés.  Elle peut signifier quelque chose  — toujours difficile à apprendre —, mais « puissante une fois apprise » ou « trop difficile ou spécialisée à vendre à tout le monde », etc.  Quelque variante de « difficult to learn, but ... » ou quelquefois « don't waste your time » est mieux en anglais, si on veut s'expliquer.